# Error: Expected function or variable

Tags: c#-4.0, vb6, com-interop

I am writing a small utility in VB6 which is calling the C#.Net class (which brings list of printers) but while calling the C# method, it is throwing below error and I am not able to compile/run the application. Can someone please help on this?

VB6 Code:

```
Dim retval As Integer
Dim tbp As NamespaceXYZ.CGETList
Dim a As String
Dim col As New Collection
Set tbp = New CGETList
retval = tbp.GetDefaultPrinterAndList(col, a)
```

C# definition for the method.

```
    public void GetDefaultPrinterAndList(ref Microsoft.VisualBasic.Collection vntPrinterList, ref string defaultPrinter)
    {
```

error:
[image: while calling the C# method, it throws the error]

Comment: Methinks you will need to use a string array instead - mixing languages types may not work.

Comment: thanks for suggestion but Just now I realize that it is throwing this error because in above code object is not getting initialized in VB.
When I added the watch, found that "tbp" is set to nothing. Any idea why?

Comment: It should take you to a specific line when you get that compile errro. Which line is it?

Comment: thanks for the suggestion guys. Just now found the cause (And Solution) why it is giving me an error. 

The problem here is that the method I have written in C# doesn't return any value whereas the invocation in VB6 is expecting some return value. Hence, I changed my method in C# to return simply integer (1) and problem got resolved. I read somewhere that we should have a return value while calling the Interop methods but I didn't give that much attention to it.

Answer (score 1):

You declared `tbp`, but forgot to initialise it.

```
Dim tbp As NamespaceXYZ.CGETList
'tbp value is currently Nothing

Set tbp = New NamespaceXYZ.CGETList
'now it's something.
```

Note that the above assumes that the `NamespaceXYZ.CGETList` class has a default constructor i.e. you can create a new object just using `New`. Some classes don't have this; they require you to create objects in other ways.